# Open "About This Mac" from Terminal?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, applescript

This probably seems totally useless to most, but i've got a specific need to open the "About This Mac" dialog from within Terminal. Any idea if its possible?

I suppose AppleScript might be the way to - what I need to do is for quality control purposes take a photo of the Mac booted into its desktop and the About This Mac screen includes its spec and serial number for proof. I suppose for a total hands off way of doing this, opening it, screenshotting it and then sending e-mail the screenshot or sending to Dropbox etc would probably be idea - I guess a screenshot is just as good as a photo with my iPhone.

Any input into either method would be excellent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also run:

```
~ system_profiler > my_profile
```

To dump much of the same information to a more parseable file called `my_profile`.

If you simply want the system's serial number (that could be sent however you want really), you could use:

```
~ system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk '/Serial/ {print $4}'
```

If you are hoping for a screenshot of About this Mac for proof of a running desktop maybe this is better:

```
~ screencapture -l \
$(osascript -e 'tell app "System Information" to id of window 1') \
system_information.png
```

Comment: Thanks Chad, yeah I wanted to prove the computer boot to desktop when it's with us really, so the last part there seems ideal (though granted it could be photoshopped obviously but still, its better than nothing)

Answer (score 0):

`open /Applications/Utilities/System\ Information.app && screencapture filename.jpg`

Will open System Information and save a screencap to filename.jpg  You can then copy/email/print/etc. that file.

System Information.app launches with a screen that shows:

- Model Name
- Model Identifier
- Processor Name
- Processor Speed
- Number of processors
- Number of cores
- L2 Cache per core
- L3 Cache
- Memory
- Boot ROM version
- SMC Version
- Serial Number
- Hardware UUID

Comment: Thanks for that, only problem is that the screenshot happens before the information app has had time to fully open - I guess I'd need a wait command

Comment: just put a `&& sleep 5 &&` between the sysinfo and the screencap